# How to flip/inverse nth bit of all binary numbers in a column using python

Tags: python, pandas

I created a dataframe where the last column shows the binary conversion of the previous column. Now I want flip the last one/two binary bits from every binary numbers of that column(R). I want flip that specific binary bit in a way that it does not affect the other bits.

How can I do that? Following is my sample code and O/P.
For example, for the 1st row, I want the binary number as 001101 (from 001100) after fliping the last bit.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(1,3,size=(10, 8)), columns=list('ABCDEFGH'))
df['Q']=df.sum(axis=1)
df['R']=df.Q.apply(lambda x: format(int(x), '06b'))
```

O/P:

```
   A  B  C  D  E  F  G  H   Q       R
0  2  2  1  1  1  1  2  2  12  001100
1  2  1  1  1  1  1  2  1  10  001010
2  2  2  1  2  2  2  1  2  14  001110
3  1  2  2  2  1  1  2  1  12  001100
4  1  2  2  1  1  2  1  1  11  001011
5  2  1  1  2  1  1  2  1  11  001011
6  1  2  2  1  1  2  1  2  12  001100
7  2  2  1  2  1  1  1  1  11  001011
8  2  1  2  2  2  2  2  1  14  001110
9  1  2  1  1  1  2  2  2  12  001100
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to use [pandas string slicing](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.slice.html)

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(1,3,size=(10, 8)), columns=list('ABCDEFGH'))
df['Q']=df.sum(axis=1)
df['R']=df.Q.apply(lambda x: format(int(x), '06b'))
print("Before:\n", df)
df.R = df.R.str.slice(stop=-1) + (1 - df.R.str.slice(start=-1).astype(int)).astype(str)
print("\nAfter:\n", df)
```

Output:

```
 Before:
    A  B  C  D  E  F  G  H   Q       R
0  1  1  2  2  1  1  1  2  11  001011
1  2  2  1  2  1  1  1  2  12  001100
2  1  1  2  1  1  1  1  1   9  001001
3  2  1  2  2  1  2  2  1  13  001101
4  1  1  2  2  1  1  1  2  11  001011
5  2  2  2  1  2  2  2  2  15  001111
6  1  2  1  2  2  1  2  1  12  001100
7  1  1  1  1  1  2  2  2  11  001011
8  1  1  1  2  1  2  1  1  10  001010
9  2  2  1  2  2  1  1  1  12  001100

After:
    A  B  C  D  E  F  G  H   Q       R
0  1  1  2  2  1  1  1  2  11  001010
1  2  2  1  2  1  1  1  2  12  001101
2  1  1  2  1  1  1  1  1   9  001000
3  2  1  2  2  1  2  2  1  13  001100
4  1  1  2  2  1  1  1  2  11  001010
5  2  2  2  1  2  2  2  2  15  001110
6  1  2  1  2  2  1  2  1  12  001101
7  1  1  1  1  1  2  2  2  11  001010
8  1  1  1  2  1  2  1  1  10  001011
9  2  2  1  2  2  1  1  1  12  001101
```

Comment: May I ask, If I want to flip bit only for first 5 rows and the rest values would be same in the new column, how can I modify that last line (string slicing)? I used df.R.loc[0:5].str.slice() but rest values filled with NaN.

Comment: Just replace loc with iloc and add to every df.R in the command and it should work

Comment: If I get you correctly, df.R= df.R.iloc[0:5].str.slice(stop=-1) + (1 - df.R.iloc[0:5].str.slice(start=-1).astype(int)).astype(str), gives first five values with bit flip and rest 5 with NaN. But I want rest 5 as previous column.

Comment: Add to left hand side as well

Comment: It works! I am getting expected values though a warning is shown "SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame".

Comment: Yeah, it's not the best syntax. Something better is to do:
`j = df.columns.get_loc("R")`
then
`df.iloc[:5, j] = df.iloc[:5, j].str.slice(stop=-1) + (1 - df.iloc[:5, j].str.slice(start=-1).astype(int)).astype(str)`

Comment: ok. As you showed me to flip the last bit, is it also possible to flip last two bits in this way. I am not sure but tried with df.R = df.R.str.slice(stop=-2) + (1 - df.R.str.slice(start=-1).astype(int)).astype(str) + (1 - df.R.str.slice(start=-1).astype(int)).astype(str). didnt work. Will appreciate your help.

Comment: Sure, just replace the first `start=-1` with `start=-2, stop=-1`